# MySql - combine REGEXP and BETWEEN functions

Tags: mysql, regex, between

I have this table.

```
+--------+----------------+
| id     | e_id           |
+--------+----------------+
| 164462 | " 3 1 2 4 6 "   |
| 164463 | " 185 1 2 4 6 " |
| 164464 | " 3 1 2 1140 6 "|
| 164465 | " 52 1 2 4 6 "  |
| 164466 | " 3 1 175 4 6 " |
| 164467 | " 3 1 2 4 6 "   |
| 164468 | " 3 1 2 4 6 "   |
| 164469 | " 3 1 2500 4 6 "|
| 164470 | " 82 1 2 4 6 "  |
| 164471 | " 3 1 2 4 6 "   |
| 164472 | " 3 1 50 4 6 "  |
| 164473 | " 3 1 2 4 6 "   |
+--------+-----------------+
```

I must find that rows that contains numbers between 175 and 2574, but numbers are separated just with `[[:space:]]`.

I was tried to use mysql query like this:

```
 select * 
   from table_name 
   where e_id between REGEXP '[[:space:]]175[[:space:]]' 
     and  REGEXP '[[:space:]]2574[[:space:]]';
```

...and a lot of combination like this one, but no luck...

Thanks For Help!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never have this kind of "list" in a single database column. In this case, you should have another table to link one `e_id` at a time.

Anyway, this is a solution to your problem **if boundaries aren't dynamic** : create a regex to match every number between 175 and 2574 :

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE e_id REGEXP("[[:space:]](1(7[5-9]|[89]\d)|[2-9]\d{2}|1\d{3}|2([0-4]\d{2}|5[0-6]\d|57[0-4]))[[:space:]]")
```

Regex details :

- `1(7[5-9]|[89]\d)` will match 175 to 199
- `[2-9]\d{2}` will match 200 to 999
- `1\d{3}` will match 1000 to 1999
- `2([0-4]\d{2}`will match 2000 to 2499
- `25[0-6]\d` will match 2500 to 2699
- `257[0-4]` will match 2570 to 2574

This solution is ugly, because your database is ugly.
It works for specific boundaries, but as you can see you'll need to rewrite another regex if you change these boundaries.

---

**What you should have:**

A table with your ids, another one with "e_ids", and then a third one to link both first :

```
CREATE TABLE `elements` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `other_elements` (
    `e_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`e_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `link_table` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `e_id` INT NOT NULL,
    INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `e_id` (`e_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK__elements` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`id`) 
        REFERENCES `elements` (`id`) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE 
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK__other_elements` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`e_id`) 
        REFERENCES `other_elements` (`e_id`) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

You then will be able to get what you want easily :

```
SELECT *
FROM elements e
JOIN link_table l
  ON l.id = e.id
WHERE l.e_id BETWEEN 175 AND 2574
```

Comment: This helped me a alot. I know that this table is written in very bad concept, but I wasn't the creator...
Thank you very much!

Comment: We don't always choose databases we work on... That's why I gave both solutions. Feel free to upvote / set this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.